# Generate Vcard using Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3, vcf-vcard

I am trying to use jeroendesloovere VCARD in Codeigniter 3 controller as below:

```
public function get_contact($unique_id)
{

            namespace JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard;
            require_once 'vendor/behat/transliterator/src/Behat/Transliterator/Transliterator.php';
            require_once 'vendor/jeroendesloovere/vcard/src/VCard.php';
            $vcardObj = new VCard();
            $status_db_customers['data']=$this->Site_model->get_customer_QR($unique_id);
            foreach ($data as $row){
                $vcardObj->addName($row->first_name. " " . $row->first_name);
                $vcardObj->addBirthday($contactResult[0]["date_of_birth"]);
                $vcardObj->addEmail($row->email);
                $vcardObj->addPhoneNumber($row->mobile);
                $vcardObj->addAddress($row->add_line_1);
            }
            return $vcardObj->download();

}
```

But this always gives an error.

Message: syntax error, unexpected token "namespace"

Please help me on how to use this ? This is inside my controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should look like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

use JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard;

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function get_contact($unique_id)
    {
        $vcardObj = new VCard();
        $status_db_customers['data']=$this->Site_model->get_customer_QR($unique_id);
        foreach ($data as $row){
            $vcardObj->addName($row->first_name. " " . $row->first_name);
            $vcardObj->addBirthday($contactResult[0]["date_of_birth"]);
            $vcardObj->addEmail($row->email);
            $vcardObj->addPhoneNumber($row->mobile);
            $vcardObj->addAddress($row->add_line_1);
        }
        return $vcardObj->download();
    }
}
```

Also make sure you've set up CodeIgniter to use Composer's autoloading file. For this you need to set `$config['composer_autoload']` in `application/config.php`, depending on where Composer's `vendor` folder is:

- If the `vendor` folder is **inside** the `application` folder, set it to `TRUE`:
  `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;`
- Or if the `vendor` folder is at a different location, specify it's path.
  For example, if the `vendor` folder is **at the same level** as the `application` folder, set it to `vendor/autoload.php`:
  `$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.